# Revert to the version of the document before workflow - Alfresco

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share

In my custom workflow, I make some changes to PDF when I create the workflow:

```
<activiti:executionListener event="start" class="pt.entp.fields.CreateFields"></activiti:executionListener>
```

I want, when I cancel the workflow, the workflow clear the changes that were made when it created. No way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First store your current version in the start workflow listener:

```
    NodeRef myPdfnode = ...
    String currentversion = serviceRegistry.getVersionService.getCurrentVersion(myPdfnode).getVersionLabel(); 
    execution.setVariable("mynode_currentversion", currentversion);
```

You will need to restore the version of the pdf document using an end workflow listener

```
 <activiti:executionListener event="end"
 class="pt.entp.fields.WorkflowEnded"></activiti:executionListener>
```

In there, check if the workflow was indeed cancelled, then restore to the  version you saved:

```
 String deleteReason = execution.getDeleteReason();

     if ("cancelled".equals(deleteReason)){
       NodeRef myPdfnode = ...
       String initialversionLabel = execution.getVaraible("mynode_currentversion");
       Version initialversion = serviceRegistry.getVersionService.getVersionHistory(myPdfnode).getVersion(initialversionLabel );
       serviceRegistry.getVersionService.revert(myPdfnode, initialversion);
     }
```

Comment: I tried it and really went for version 1.0, however the document was the same with the fields that I create when I start the workflow.

Comment: I suspect my code for reverting the version is not good. not sure how to do it. You can find example code in ScriptNode.java source, there is a revert() method.

Comment: I ve updated the answer. It now reverts to the first version. If you need a different version, store the version in the wf executioncontext of your startlistener, and find that version in the endlistener.

Comment: `cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getRootVersion(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef)`

Comment: How can I save the actual version in the wf execution context of my startlistener? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Added version storing in workflow executioncontext to code